# tinymce and responsive line-breaks (short words after a period)

Tags: tinymce, responsive, line-breaks

With the advent of many different screensizes, manual line ending (not sentence-endings) has become a bit of a guessing/repetitive task. I want to avoid having the first short word of a new sentence on the ending of the line all by itself on smaller screens.

After a period, at the start of a new sentence, is there a way to make 1, 2 or 3-letter words be followed automatically by a non-breaking-space instead of a normal space in tinymce?

Comment: Any solution wouldn't be related to TinyMCE, but I believe there are multiple pure CSS solutions. Any server side implementation would need you to post the code to be viable, otherwise any solution would be incredibly generic with no clues how/where to apply it. How are you using TinyMCE? And can you edit your question to include the code you have? How is the content saved/stored?

Comment: Thanks for your recation, however I fail to see your point, especially regarding the CSS bit. I'm asking how to get tinymce to replace a space with a nbsp; in the text view (html of old) under certain conditions (when, after a period, a word is 1 or 2 or 3 letters max, replace the space with a nbsp; behind it). Tinymce is used in a translation editor in WP, and vanilla for now.

Comment: I have added this to my child theme's functions.php to make tiny keep &nbsp; and &shy; in text view:
`// Show &shy; and &nbsp; in TinyMCE editor's text mode
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
 // Add entities to the default array (nbsp, shy) 
 $initArray['entities'] .= ',160,nbsp,173,shy'; 
 $initArray['entity_encoding'] = 'named';

 return $initArray; 
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
`

Comment: Never mind, I found a brilliant javascript which solves his issue and others:
[link](https://github.com/nathanford/ragadjust)